# SQL filtering, select specific values count when condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count

Maybe I am just being dumb, but for some reason, this is working and yes, it works great but we wanted to add a condition with a sub table but maintainig same format.

BEGIN

```
SELECT 
         v.[id]
        ,v.[Vacante]
        ,v.[deptoId]
        ,v.[StatusId]
        ,v.[scholarYearId]
        ,v.[tipoVacanteId]
        ,v.[detalle]                
        ,v.[createdDate]
        ,v.[createdBy]
        ,d.nombre as DeptoNombre
        ,s.nombre as statusNombre
        ,y.nombre as scholarYearNombre
        ,t.nombre as tipoVacanteNombre
        ,count(uv.id) as totalCandidatos
FROM 
        [dbo].[tbl_vacantes] v
LEFT JOIN
        tbl_usuariosPorVacante uv on v.id = uv.vacanteId
--LEFT JOIN
--      dbo.[tbl_user] u  on uv.userId=u.id
INNER JOIN 
        dbo.[tbl_depto] d ON d.Id = v.[deptoId] 
INNER JOIN 
        dbo.[tbl_status] s ON s.Id = v.[statusId]   
LEFT JOIN
        tbl_scholarYear y ON v.scholarYearId=y.Id   
LEFT JOIN
        tbl_tipoVacante t ON v.tipoVacanteId=t.Id                           
--WHERE
--  u.progressId =3 OR u.progressId is null --Solo usuarios que ya temrinaron su proceso.           
GROUP BY
         v.[id]
        ,v.[Vacante]
        ,v.[deptoId]
        ,v.[StatusId]
        ,v.[scholarYearId]
        ,v.[tipoVacanteId]  
        ,v.[detalle]                        
        ,v.[createdDate]
        ,v.[createdBy]
        ,d.nombre 
        ,s.nombre
        ,y.nombre
        ,t.nombre
ORDER BY
        v.id DESC
```

END

What we want to do, is in totalCandidatos (the count) keep a count, yes, but only count when dbo.[tbl_user] u has progressId = 3 and 4. Since now, it is counting all kind of progressId.

I know, it may be dumb. But Im stuck in this one.

Thanks!

Comment: `where tbl_user in (3,4)`

Comment: Do you want to exclude non 3/4 rows or include but with a count of 0?

Comment: I want to just take in the count(), the ones that tbl_user.progressID = 4 or 3. Not the whole universer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sum(case when <condition> then 1 else 0 end)` to count the number of records returned that meet a certain criteria.

Comment: As a mattter of fact, I did that but it is just returning 0.

  left join
      tbl_user u on uv.userId = u.id ------ >at the end of the joins

and instad of count.... sum(case when (u.progressId = 3) then 1 else 0 end) as totalCandidatos.... All I get is 0

Comment: Works like a charm!